# How to restrict user input with a yes or no question python

Tags: python-3.x

If the user entry is anything but yes/no in the el-if and nested if statements it should print Invalid Entry.

```
comedy=input('Would you like to see a comedy (yes / no)?')
if(comedy=='yes'):
    print('You might like either Yes Minister or SPAM lot')
    elif(comedy=='no'):
    musical=input('Would you like to see a musical (yes / no)?')`your text`
    if(musical=='yes'):
        print('You might like either Les Miss or Mamma Mia')`your text`
    elif (musical=='no'):`your text`
        print('You might like either The Woman in Black or Macbeth')`your text`
else:
    print('Invalid Entry')`your text`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct however is not indented correctly, see below

```
comedy=input('Would you like to see a comedy (yes / no)?')
if(comedy=='yes'):
    print('You might like either Yes Minister or SPAM lot')
elif(comedy=='no'):
    musical=input('Would you like to see a musical (yes / no)?')`your text`
    if(musical=='yes'):
        print('You might like either Les Miss or Mamma Mia')`your text`
    elif (musical=='no'):`your text`
        print('You might like either The Woman in Black or Macbeth')`your text`
    else:
        print('Invalid Entry')`your text`
else:
    print('Invalid Entry')`your text`
```

Alternatively, control flow with return statements:

```
comedy=input('Would you like to see a comedy (yes / no)?')

if(comedy=='yes'):
    print('You might like either Yes Minister or SPAM lot')
    return

elif(comedy=='no'):
    musical=input('Would you like to see a musical (yes / no)?')`your text`

    if(musical=='yes'):
        print('You might like either Les Miss or Mamma Mia')`your text`
    return

    elif (musical=='no'):`your text`
        print('You might like either The Woman in Black or Macbeth')`your text`
    return

print('Invalid Entry')`your text
```